# Python setup.py to run shell script

Tags: python, setuptools

I need to run my own script during 'sdist' phase while creating Python package.
I wrote the following script. Do you know better approach? Could you recommend please the better one or link to the official documentation on setuptools where this moment has been explained?

```
import subprocess
import sys

from setuptools import setup, find_packages, os

if 'sdist' in sys.argv:
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir('website/static/stylesheets/')
    result = subprocess.call("scss --update --compass ./*.scss", shell=True)
    if result != 0:
        exit(1)
    os.chdir(cwd)

setup(name = "site",
    author="Vladimir Ignatev",
    author_email="mail@gmail.com",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=True,
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Although this comes pretty late, here is a solution proposal.

Basically, it is simply subclassing the `distutils`' `sdist` command with adding custom logic and registering it in the setup function. [Unfortunately, the official documentation to this topic is kind of vague and laconic](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/apiref.html#creating-a-new-distutils-command); [Extending Distutils](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/extending.html) provides at least a tiny example for the start. I found it much better to read the code of modules in `distutils.command` package to see how the actual commands are implemented.

To execute an arbitrary command, you can use the method `distutils.cmd.Command::spawn` that executes passed input string, raising a `DistutilsExecError` if the command's exit code in not zero:

```
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist as sdist_orig
from distutils.errors import DistutilsExecError

from setuptools import setup  


class sdist(sdist_orig):

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.spawn(['ls', '-l'])
        except DistutilsExecError:
            self.warn('listing directory failed')
        super().run()


setup(name='spam',
    version='0.1',
    packages=[],
    cmdclass={
        'sdist': sdist
    }
)
```

Running the setup script above yields:

```
$ python setup.py sdist
running sdist
ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 hoefling  staff   52 23 Dez 19:06 MANIFEST
drwxr-xr-x  3 hoefling  staff   96 23 Dez 19:06 dist
-rw-r--r--  1 hoefling  staff  484 23 Dez 19:07 setup.py
running check
...
writing manifest file 'MANIFEST'
creating spam-0.1
making hard links in spam-0.1...
hard linking setup.py -> spam-0.1
Creating tar archive
removing 'spam-0.1' (and everything under it)
```

#### Reusing commands

Here is (although simplified) a real life example of a command we are using in our projects that is used around NodeJS projects and invokes `yarn`:

```
import distutils
import os
import pathlib
import setuptools

_YARN_CMD_SEP = ';'

_HELP_MSG_SUBCMD = (
    'yarn subcommands to execute (separated '
    'by {})'.format(_YARN_CMD_SEP)
)

_HELP_MSG_PREFIX = (
    'path to directory containing package.json. '
    'If not set, current directory is assumed.'
)


class yarn(setuptools.Command):

    description = ('runs yarn commands. Assumes yarn is '
                   'already installed by the user.')

    user_options = [
        ('subcommands=', None, _HELP_MSG_SUBCMD),
        ('prefix=', None, _HELP_MSG_PREFIX),
    ]

    def initialize_options(self) -> None:
        self.subcommands = []
        self.prefix = None  # type: pathlib.Path

    def finalize_options(self) -> None:
        self.subcommands = [
            cmd.strip() for cmd in str(self.subcommands).split(self._YARN_CMD_SEP)
        ]
        self.prefix = pathlib.Path(self.prefix) if self.prefix else pathlib.Path()

    def run(self) -> None:
        cwd = pathlib.Path().absolute()
        os.chdir(str(self.prefix.absolute()))  # change to prefix dir
        for cmd in self.subcommands:
            self.announce('running yarn {} ...'.format(cmd), level=distutils.log.INFO)
            self.spawn(['yarn'] + cmd.split(' '))
        os.chdir(str(cwd))  # change back to our previous dir
```

Example usage:

```
$ python setup.py yarn --prefix=. --subcommands="add leftpad; remove leftpad"
running yarn
running yarn add leftpad ...
yarn add leftpad
yarn add v1.3.2
warning package.json: No license field
warning No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
└─ leftpad@0.0.1
warning No license field
✨  Done in 0.33s.
running yarn remove leftpad ...
yarn remove leftpad
yarn remove v1.3.2
warning package.json: No license field
[1/2] Removing module leftpad...
[2/2] Regenerating lockfile and installing missing dependencies...
warning No license field
success Uninstalled packages.
✨  Done in 0.13s.
```

You can also use the `yarn` in your command chain as every other command: `python setup.py yarn test sdist` etc.