# Include all files and directories in Source distribution package

Tags: python, shell

I have a following project folder `(shell_test)` structure

[image]

I am trying to prepare a source distribution file which includes all files and directories in the project folder `shell_test` and run the `script.sh` immediately when I try to install the package created.

I tried

```
setup(
        name='Test Package',
        version='0.0.1',
        description='test',
        author='test user',
        author_email='test@test.com',
        url='https://test.com/test',
        packages=find_packages(),
        package_data={
                     '': [],
                     },
        include_package_data=True,
        )
```

Comment: You need to specify the files you want to be included in your package with MANIFEST.in https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/

Comment: @Sr.S Thankyou for the quick reply. How to run the `script.sh` immediately when I try to install the package created using `pip install package_name` .
I am trying to run the package using `subprocess.call(['./setup/linux/script.sh'])`

Comment: You can execute code during setup.py, take a look a this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47955639/4305230